# regex extract data

Tags: regex, expression, geoserver

I'm new on regular expression and I'm spending last two days about my problem.

I have a string like this:

```
38_285_4461_186_S2A_MSIL2A_20180119T101331_N0206_R022_T32TQQ_20180119T135441
```

and I need four regex expression to extraxt data from this string in four parts:

1. 38
2. 285
3. 4461
4. 186

I have more string to evaluate and this values are variable, each group contains only number, but number of digits are variable

example of string template are:

```
xx_xxx_xxxx_xx_S2...................... (where x is a digit and is variable)
```

I tried the following regex

```
^(?:[^_]*\_){1}([^_]*)
```

edit:
I need four regex expression, one for "group" and result is full match. 
I can't use java. Regular expression will be used in geoserver.
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_time-elevationseries.html

Comment: Your nickname suggests `Java`, is this the programming language you're trying to accomplish this in?

Comment: See [`^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/MSU8Wb/1)

Comment: @Jan I just follow the original pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Which is good, but the question clearly states *each group contains only number, but number of digits are variable*.

Comment: Can't you use a regular `split("_")`?

Comment: @Jan, I am not sure it is that  important. Probably, OP needs [`\G(\d+)_(?=(?:\d+_)*S2)`](https://regex101.com/r/MSU8Wb/2). Or `s.replaceFirst("(?s)_S2.*", "").split("_")`.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use

```
^(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)
```

or simply split on the `_` and use the array parts.
See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/boh5QO/1/).

Comment: This pattern looks like funny heads

Comment: I need four regex expression, one for "group" and result is full match.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex to solve this problem, you can simply use `split` like this:

```
String[] values = "38_285_4461_186_S2A_MSIL2...".split("_")
// values[0] => 38
// values[1] => 285
// values[2] => 4461
// values[3] => 186
```

Comment: I can't use java. Regular expression will be used in geoserver. http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_time-elevationseries.html